# Nginx transforms X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" to "DENY, SAMEORIGIN"

Tags: nginx

I have this in my `nginx` configuration `add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;`
And from the client side, I always get `"DENY, SAMEORIGIN"`.
This is not logical, I should get `"SAMEORIGIN"` *only*.

I'm sure `nginx` takes in account my configuration, because if I comment it, and restart the server, from the client side, I only get `"DENY"`.

I can't find anywhere in the documentation that when you `add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;` `nginx` still keeps the `"DENY"` option... and from [here](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet.html):

> There are three possible values for the X-Frame-Options header:
>
> - DENY, which prevents any domain from framing the content. The "DENY" setting is > recommended unless a specific need has been identified for framing.
> - SAMEORIGIN, which only allows the current site to frame the content.
> - ALLOW-FROM uri, which permits the specified 'uri' to frame this page. (e.g., ALLOW-FROM http://www.example.com).

You cant find a value like `"DENY, SAMEORIGIN"`.
What am I missing?